# Symfony2 Doctrine Use Cache Tables

Tags: database, caching, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

For the project I'm working on, we have a fully normalized database where no information is redundant.

I'd like to keep this method, but also add "cache" tables, which are essentially tables which have pre-computed information. I'd love to be able to have this information in separate tables (which could then be blown away and regenerated as needed).

For example, part of this involves a forum. One "cached" value would be the number of posts a user has made. There is no need to keep this in any of the normalized tables, because it can be calculated based on a count of posts linked with that user. However, this is a (relatively) expensive call, so the cache table would keep track of this value for me and I can pull from it as needed.

I'm also strongly considering using a NoSQL database like MongoDB for this, because the cached tables would essentially have no joins or foreign keys (making it perfect for MongoDB).

Any ideas how I should approach this using Doctrine in Symfony2? Anyone done this before?

Thanks a ton!

## Update

As greg0ire comments, it looks like Doctrine has some built in caching functionality: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html

Does anyone know if I can employ this to cache my values without storing them in the database?

For example, if I had an unmapped property $postCount, can I use Doctrine to cache that value (or I guess, the object with that value populated)?

The only problem with this approach (caching to memory instead of a database), is we're working in a clustered environment, so I'd either have to build the cache multiple times (each server the user hits), or set get a shared caching server set up (which is a bit tricky).

I'll continue to investigate this route, but does anyone know of any database stored methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that doctrine2 has a [built-in caching system](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html) ?

Comment: I was not. If I'm understanding it correctly, that may be precisely what I am looking for. Once I get time to actually write some code to try things out, I'll reply back.

Comment: The result cache won't be able to cache unmapped properties, since I guess they won't be hydrated after a query. The result cache caches query results. You may set a shared caching server, or several cache servers, look at the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for [Doctrine's result cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache)
Here is [the related part of the sf2 configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers).